# My PowerShell script does not work after moving script files to another location?

Tags: powershell

I am having a hard time trying to figure out why my script does not work whenever I move the script files from one location to another.

Could it be that I am using absolute paths instead of relative paths?

The code below works, but whenever I move the files to a different location and change the path locations (`$ServerPath` and `$ServicesPath`), it doesn't fully execute the script.

```
#stop and start Services for Windows Patching
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $ComputerName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $Action
)

Write-Host "" -ForegroundColor Cyan

try {
    if ($ComputerName -eq "archive" -and $Action -eq "start") {
        $ServerPath = "C:\temp\OTCS Non-Prod\CSIRT Final\otcs resources\sbxnames.start.otcs.txt"
        $ServicesPath = "C:\temp\OTCS Non-Prod\CSIRT Final\otcs resources\sbxservice.start.otcs.txt"
    } elseif ($ComputerName -eq "archive" -and $Action -eq "stop") {
        $ServerPath = "C:\temp\OTCS Non-Prod\CSIRT Final\otcs resources\sbxnames.stop.otcs.txt"
        $ServicesPath = "C:\temp\OTCS Non-Prod\CSIRT Final\otcs resources\sbxservice.stop.otcs.txt"
    } elseif ($ComputerName -eq "admin" -and $Action -eq "start") {
        $ServerPath = "C:\temp\OTCS Non-Prod\CSIRT Final\otcs resources\adminservers.start.otcs.txt"
        $ServicesPath = "C:\temp\OTCS Non-Prod\CSIRT Final\otcs resources\adminnames.start.otcs.txt"
    } elseif ($ComputerName -eq "admin" -and $Action -eq "stop") {
        $ServerPath = "C:\temp\OTCS Non-Prod\CSIRT Final\otcs resources\adminservers.stop.otcs.txt"
        $ServicesPath = "C:\temp\OTCS Non-Prod\CSIRT Final\otcs resources\adminnames.stop.otcs.txt"
    } elseif ($ComputerName -eq "front end" -and $Action -eq "start") {
        $ServerPath = "C:\temp\OTCS Non-Prod\CSIRT Final\otcs resources\frontendservers.start.otcs.txt"
        $ServicesPath = "C:\temp\OTCS Non-Prod\CSIRT Final\otcs resources\frontendnames.start.otcs.txt"
    } elseif ($ComputerName -eq "front end" -and $Action -eq "stop") {
        $ServerPath = "C:\temp\OTCS Non-Prod\CSIRT Final\otcs resources\frontendservers.stop.otcs.txt"
        $ServicesPath = "C:\temp\OTCS Non-Prod\CSIRT Final\otcs resources\frontendnames.stop.otcs.txt"
    }

    $ComputerName = Get-Content -Path $ServerPath

    if ($ComputerName -ne $null) {
        $ServiceNames = Get-Content -Path $ServicesPath
        foreach ($c in $ComputerName) {
            foreach ($s in $ServiceNames) {
                $sn = Get-Service -Name $s -ComputerName $c -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

                if ($Action -eq "start") {
                    if ($sn.Status -eq "Running") {
                        Write-Host $s "is already running on $c" -ForegroundColor Green
                        Write-Host "---------------------"
                    } elseif ($sn.Status -eq "stopped") {
                        Write-Host "Starting $s on $c..." -ForegroundColor Green
                        Start-Service $sn -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                        $sn.WaitForStatus("Running")
                        Start-Sleep -s 3
                        $sn.Refresh()
                        Write-Output $sn
                        Write-Host "---------------------"
                    } else {
                        Write-Host $sn.Status
                        Write-Host "---------------------"
                    }
                } elseif ($Action -eq "stop") {
                    if ($sn.Status -eq "Running") {
                        Write-Host "Stopping $s on $c..." -ForegroundColor Green
                        Stop-Service $sn -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                        $sn.WaitForStatus("Stopped")
                        Start-Sleep -s 3
                        $sn.Refresh()
                        Write-Output $sn
                        Write-Host "---------------------"
                    } elseif ($sn.Status -eq "stopped") {
                        Write-Host $s "is already stopped on $c"  -ForegroundColor Green
                        Write-Host "---------------------"
                    } else {
                        Write-Host $sn.Status
                        Write-Host "---------------------"
                    }
                } else {
                    Write-Host "Invalid Action.  Please type either START or STOP." -ForegroundColor Red
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "Invalid Server Name" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host $_
}
Read-Host -Prompt "Press any key to exit..."
```

When the script runs, it displays this

```
PS C:\temp\OTCS Non-Prod\CSIRT Final\Windows Patching> .\Maintain- 
OTCSServices.ps1
cmdlet Maintain-OTCSServices.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ComputerName: archive
Action: stop

Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'Ascent Capture 
Service'.
At C:\temp\OTCS Non-Prod\CSIRT Final\Windows Patching\Maintain- 
OTCSServices.ps1:49 char:23
+                 $sn = Get-Service -Name $s -ComputerName $c <#-ErrorA ...
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Ascent Capture Service:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

---------------------

Press any key to exit...:
```

Comment: what does "it doesn't run the script" mean? are there any errors listed anywhere?

Comment: it runs but it doesn't execute any of the commands within the script.  It seems like it runs through the script, but doesn't actually perform any of the steps, until the end - which is "Press any key to exit...:"

I've added the output once I run the script.

Comment: go back and remove the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` directives to see what the errors are.[*grin*] ///// also ... why do you have a TRY wrapped around THE ENTIRE CORE OF THE SCRIPT? [*frown*] that is supposed to be used around _specific_ bits of code ... SHORT, specific bits of code. why? so that your `catch` is catching at the error instead of twenty or thirty lines away from the error. [*grin*]

Comment: I have removed the erroraction and posted the error message above.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Fairly new to powershell so I had thought the try catch statements were to be wrapped around the entire core.  Do you have a recommendation on where to put my TRY and CATCH statements?

Comment: from what i understand of your code, the`try/catch` seems to be best wrapped around the various `*-service` calls. either one per such call, or one around the entire list. the recommended place is per-thing-that-may-fail. [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Regarding the originally issue, the error message states it cannot find the service with the name 'Ascent Capture Service'.  Is there a reason why this is the case?  The only change is the path location of the files.

Comment: my 1st thot would be that the `-ComputerName $c` is not valid. you will need to check what each such line is expanding to. that cmdlet does not have a `-WhatIf` parameter, so perhaps doing a `Write-Host [all the variables here]` would help you visualize the situation.

Comment: I think the most likely issue is that it does not like where you are placing the files when you move them, or you have entered the path incorrectly. Remember you can always Shift+Right Click to get the 'Copy as path' option, and then just paste the full path to the file into your script.

Comment: So after further debugging, I've found out that when I run the script the first time in the ISE window, the foreach loop takes all the server names instead of reading it line by line.  So it's reading server1 server2 instead of just server1.  However, if I run it the 2nd time, it reads it line by line (server1 only).  Why is this the case?

Comment: I figured it out.  Changed parameter name to something else as there was a duplicate in my code.  Thanks everyone.